# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to connect through Postman Using PyCharm

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, postman

Hi I am trying to test my connection to my database on my local drive for a personal project I am working on. I am trying to get better with python and MongoDB. Every time I try to test my connection using postman I am getting a 500 internal error. I double checked my URI = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 like majority local. I even uninstalled and reinstalled mongoDB. Any advice or solutions would be highly helpful. In my PyCharm IDE I have my database file

```
import pymongo

__author__ = 'jslvtr'

class Database(object):
URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
DATABASE = None

@staticmethod
def initialize():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
    Database.DATABASE = client['fullstack']

@staticmethod
def insert(collection, data):
    Database.DATABASE[collection].insert(data)

@staticmethod
def find(collection, query):
    return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)

@staticmethod
def find_one(collection, query):
    return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query)
```

Here is my app file:

```
from flask import Flask
from src.common.database import Database

__author__ = 'jslvtr'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.secret_key ='123'


@app.before_first_request
def init_db():
    Database.initialize()


from src.models.users.views import user_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(user_blueprint, url_prefix="/users")
```

Here is my config file:

```
__author__ = 'jslvtr'


DEBUG = True
ADMINS = frozenset([
    "christopher.jxxxx@gmail.com"
])
```

This is the error I keep receiving:
DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"
500 Internal Server Error
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode to see what line produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

You must check mongodb from command line first like below

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo localhost:27017 ;

if it works then you can jump into the code;

the issue you are getting error 500 is reserved for server only, meaning it doesn't link to your database connectivity at all. The request you are sending is wrong as per the REST endpoint you defined. Please verify the request with your code. If the request matches with your code you will get connection timeout error from MongoDB if you cannot connect to mongodb from localhost.

I think once you are okay with request you will be able to get a success.

You can paste the request JSON for more help.